# Why does unordered_set::begin() change if no rehashing occurs?

Tags: c++, hash, iterator

Based on reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace, it states: Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than max_load_factor()*bucket_count().

In this code:

```
int main() 
{ 
    unordered_set<int> myset;
    myset.emplace(4);
    cout << myset.bucket_count() << endl;
    cout << myset.max_load_factor() << endl;

    auto it = myset.begin();
    myset.emplace(3);
    cout << (it == myset.begin()) << endl;
}
```

There is no rehashing when I do emplace the second time (bucket count is 2 and max load factor is 1 right before emplacing the second time, which is not more than the new number of elements, 2), but my `begin()` iterator changes. Why is this iterator invalidated/changed even though there is no rehashing?

Comment: When you insert an item into a container it can change what is the first item in the container. This has nothing to do with rehashing or iterator invalidation. Your `it` iterator is still valid, it's just not pointing to the start of the container anymore.

Comment: @john Does changing what the first item is mean the begin iterator was invalidated?

Comment: No, rehashing would make all iterators invalid, but there's no rehashing here.

Comment: I guess you're confused over what it means when an iterator is invalid. An invalid iterator can no longer be used. Your code is still using `it`, it's still a valid iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As john already mentioned, your iterator is still valid but it points to the begin() of your unordered_set container at the moment where there was only one element '4'.

So, one thing you should keep in mind using C++ iterators - don't cache them at all! Unless you don't forget to update the iterator every time you do change the container invariants.